# Chain of POST requests in Objective C (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, http, post

I need to send a server a set of requests with some data. The data in the subsequent requests will be determined based on the server response in the earlier requests. I do not want to use synchronous approach with `NSURLConnection` class, as it is very limiting (for one of the requests, for instance, i need to prevent redirects. According to Apple Dev documentation this can only be done with Delegate implementation).

Depending on which request in the chain it is, i need to be doing different things (send different messages to various classes).

The way i see it now, is that i have to either create n delegates for each of my requests, or create a delegate which would `initWithFlag` and then create the instances of that delegate with different flags, or i need to use something like a factory pattern which would be pretty similar solution to the second one.

I do not WANT to implement a delegate at all, i want to send requests with the least bit of coding possible.
I am also not looking at any frameworks (ASIHTTPRequest etc), i would like to do it with the native classes.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Saying you don't want to use a delegate or any frameworks is like saying I want to paint my bedroom but i don't want to use a brush, or tape anything, or cover anything, because its too much work.  Using AFNetworking would make this task so much easier and solid!

Comment: The idea i have is that i want to try and achieve something using the built in frameworks. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled on implementing the delegate after all.
The key things that tripped me were:

1. Do NOT declare the delegate methods in .h file. They won't work like that. Simply add them to implementation.
2. A delegate can be init'ed within the `NSURLConnection` `initWithRequest` method or it can be held as a property of the parent class, there is no difference.
3. The best way to handle multiple requests is the suggested `initWithFlag`. Therefore, it is best to create a delegate when initialising connection. The delegate lives long enough to perform full data transfer under ARC.
4. The most convenient way to cancel the redirect comes from Apple's Developer Library:

   ```
     -(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection  
       willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  
      redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse  
   {  
   NSURLRequest *newRequest = request;  
   if (redirectResponse)   
   {  
       newRequest = nil;  
   }  
   return newRequest;  
   }
   ```

   Please note that this message is sent several times during the life of the connection for undisclosed reasons. However, if the response is not an actual redirect, the         `redirectResponse` will be `nil`.
   Setting the request to `nil` will cancel the redirect, but `NSURLConnection` will finish processing the original data (that is, `connectionDidFinishLoading` message will be sent).
   You can cancel this behaviour by sending this message: 
   `[connection cancel];`
5. I found `NSNotifications` to be the best way to pass results to the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to use third party frameworks, but I'd really suggest AFNetworking. With that said, you do not NEED AFNetworking or any third party library, it will just make your life easier IMHO.

So, what I have done in a similar scenario is essentially use the Command Pattern. When I want to send off one of these complicated "requests" I initialize a command object, set all of the necessary parameters and then call `execute`. My command object has completion and failure handlers/blocks and `execute` is an asynchronous call.

Within the command I have different 'steps' that are effectively synchronous and depend on each other. Let's say request A depends on B and B depends on C, the first step of the command is to execute A on it's own queue (I am using GCD with a private queue) and wait for it to finish. Once A finishes (successfully) I continue on to B and pass in any results I need from A into B. Likewise for B->C. If any of the intermediate requests fail throughout the process I can execute the `failure` block and handle it from where I executed the command (consumer end). If all finish successfully I execute the `success` block.

I prefer the encapsulation of this approach as it is very easy to re-use throughout the project, all of the intricacies are tucked away in the command's implementation.

Oh and the fact that I use callbacks/blocks I did not need to implement any delegates. In your case using the NSURL classes your command object would be the delegate of any of those instances.

Comment: Chris, this sounds promising, but are you doing it with AFNetworking? Because the synchronous execution of NSURLConnection doesn't allow for modification of redirect response behaviour, hence it is unusable this way, and i am still stuck creating a delegate.

Comment: I am, but I don't quite see why that is going to determine if you can or cannot follow this approach. Maybe you can explain more what you mean by redirect behavior? "I do not WANT to implement a delegate at all" Are you saying that you do not even want to conform to already defined protocols? Or are you saying that you do not want to create your own protocol?

Comment: I am basically translating this from c# where  my execution follows this logic - i create a request, then begin asynchronous execution which calls back a method that adds the body and begins asynchronous GetResponse, which calls back another method that creates another request and so on. So it is pretty similar to your blocks approach, although not a Command. The problem i have is if i use `NSURLConnections`' `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` method, i can not tell it to return the original data, not the redirected response.

Comment: In one of requests the server will redirect me several times and using the synchronous method will return the NSData of the last response. I need the NSData of the first response. According to this: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-170129) i can not specify that i want the original response with the `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error` method.